# making a correct binary tree

Tags: java, binary-tree

```
    private void dcHullForUpperHull(List<Point> list, Point p, Point q) {
    List<Point> upperH = new ArrayList<Point>();
    List<Point> lowerH = new ArrayList<Point>();
    int low = 0;
    int high = list.size()-1;

    System.out.println(list);
    if(low<high) {

        Point pivot = list.get((low+high)/2);

        for (Point point : list) {
            boolean bool = Determinate.isPointLeftSide(q, pivot, point);

            if (bool == true ) {
                upperH.add(point);
            }
        }
        for (Point point : list) {
            boolean bool = Determinate.isPointLeftSide(pivot, p, point);
            boolean bool1 = Determinate.isPointOnLine(pivot, p, point);
            if (bool == true || bool1==true) {
                lowerH.add(point);
            }
        }

        System.out.println(pivot.toString());
        System.out.println(upperH.toString());
        System.out.println(lowerH.toString());

        dcHullForUpperHull(upperH, pivot, q);           
        dcHullForUpperHull(lowerH, p, pivot);



    }
}
```

and it prints:

```
[X :132.0  Y: 140.0angle0.0, X :162.0  Y: 116.0angle0.0, X :210.0  Y: 112.0angle0.0, `enter code here`X:258.0  Y: 117.0angle0.0]
X :162.0  Y: 116.0angle0.0
[X :210.0  Y: 112.0angle0.0, X :258.0  Y: 117.0angle0.0]
[X :132.0  Y: 140.0angle0.0, X :162.0  Y: 116.0angle0.0]
[X :210.0  Y: 112.0angle0.0, X :258.0  Y: 117.0angle0.0]
X :210.0  Y: 112.0angle0.0
[X :258.0  Y: 117.0angle0.0]
[X :210.0  Y: 112.0angle0.0]
[X :258.0  Y: 117.0angle0.0]
[X :210.0  Y: 112.0angle0.0]
[X :132.0  Y: 140.0angle0.0, X :162.0  Y: 116.0angle0.0]
X :132.0  Y: 140.0angle0.0
[]
[X :132.0  Y: 140.0angle0.0]
[]
[X :132.0  Y: 140.0angle0.0]
```

And it is clear that my binary tree is not OK!! also a method `"isPointLeftSide"` will say that the point is left of one line with its determinate.But my main problem is that : the binary tree is not OK.and I will have some empty external nodes.
please help me
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code doesn't **make** a binary tree. It is almost quicksorting (well, you do the pivot, the partition and the recursive call, but don't put the sorted list together again; hence almost) the original list. Can you specify what you actually are thinking of doing?

Comment: I have a question that can I merge two external node which one is empty?

Comment: It's impossible to answer this question, because the data type for the tree isn't even in the program! But in general, each node in a _binary_ tree should either be a leaf node (no children), or an internal node (2 children)

Answer (score 0):

You can see a perfect example of a working unbalanced binary tree at [Litterate Programs](http://en.literateprograms.org/Special%3aDownloadcode/Binary_search_tree_%28Java%29).
But you know, if i were you, i would instead use either `TreeSet` or `TreeMap`, which are perfect implementations, provided you give them a valid comparator, which you already have written, in one form or one another.

Answer (score 0):

Thins kind of thing is almost impossible to debug just by looking at it. I suggest writing a validation method that checkes the tree structure for correctness, then calling it after each operation on the tree. That should help you pinpoint when and where exactly things go wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code i used to implement binary tree and its operations:

```
<?php
```

class Node
{
 public $data;
 public $leftChild;
 public $rightChild;

public function __construct($data)
  {
   $this->data=$data;
   $this->leftChild=null;
   $this->rightChild=null;
  }
 public function disp_data()
  {
   echo $this->data;
  }

}//end class Node
class BinaryTree
{
 public $root;
 //public $s;
 public function __construct()
  {
   $this->root=null;
   //$this->s=file_get_contents('store');

}
//function to display the tree
  public function display()
  {
   $this->display_tree($this->root);

}
  public function display_tree($local_root)
  {

if($local_root==null) 
     return;
    $this->display_tree($local_root->leftChild);
    echo $local_root->data."
";
    $this->display_tree($local_root->rightChild);

} 
// function to insert a new node
  public function insert($key)
   {
    $newnode=new Node($key);
      if($this->root==null)
        {
         $this->root=$newnode;
         return;
        }
      else
        {
         $parent=$this->root;
         $current=$this->root;
           while(true)
             {
               $parent=$current;
                 //$this->find_order($key,$current->data);
                if($key==($this->find_order($key,$current->data)))
                  {
                      $current=$current->leftChild;
                       if($current==null)
                         {
                          $parent->leftChild=$newnode;
                          return;
                         }//end if2
                  }//end if1 
                else
                  {
                      $current=$current->rightChild;
                       if($current==null)
                         {
                          $parent->rightChild=$newnode;
                          return;
                         } //end if1
                  } //end else
             }//end while loop 
        }//end else

} //end insert function

//function to search a particular Node
 public function find($key)
  {
    $current=$this->root;
     while($current->data!=$key)
          {
            if($key==$this->find_order($key,$current->data))
              {
                $current=$current->leftChild;
              }
            else
              {
                $current=$current->rightChild;
              }
            if($current==null)
              return(null);

```
      }
     return($current->data);
```

}// end the function to search
 public function delete1($key)
  {
    $current=$this->root;
    $parent=$this->root;

```
$isLeftChild=true;
 while($current->data!=$key)
      {
       $parent=$current;
       if($key==($this->find_order($key,$current->data)))
         {
          $current=$current->leftChild;
          $isLeftChild=true;
         }   
       else
         {
          $current=$current->rightChild;
          $isLeftChild=false;   
         } 
        if($current==null)
          return(null);
      }//end while loop 

  echo "<br/><br/>Node to delete:".$current->data;
 //to delete a leaf node 
 if($current->leftChild==null&&$current->rightChild==null)
   {
       if($current==$this->root)
          $this->root=null;  
      else if($isLeftChild==true)
       {
        $parent->leftChild=null;
       }  
     else
       {
        $parent->rightChild=null;
       }
     return($current);       
   }//end if1
 //to delete a node having a leftChild
```

else if($current->rightChild==null)
       {
          if($current==$this->root)
           $this->root=$current->leftChild;
          else if($isLeftChild==true)
           {
            $parent->leftChild=$current->leftChild;
           }
          else
           {
            $parent->rightChild=$current->leftChild;
           }
          return($current);
       }//end else if1
    //to delete a node having a rightChild
   else if($current->leftChild==null)
       {
         if($current==$this->root)
           $this->root=$current->rightChild;
         else if($isLeftChild==true)
           {
            $parent->leftChild=$current->rightChild;
           }
         else
           {
            $parent->rightChild=$current->rightChild; 
           }
           return($current);
       }
   //to delete a node having both childs
    else
       {
        $successor=$this->get_successor($current);
        if($current==$this->root)
          {
            $this->root=$successor;

```
      }
    else if($isLeftChild==true)
      {
       $parent->leftChild=$successor;
      }
    else
      {
       $parent->rightChild=$successor;
      }     
     $successor->leftChild=$current->leftChild;
    return($current);
   }
```

}//end the function to delete a node
//Function to find the successor node
 public function get_successor($delNode)
  {
   $succParent=$delNode;
   $successor=$delNode;
   $temp=$delNode->rightChild;
    while($temp!=null)
         {
          $succParent=$successor;
          $successor=$temp;
          $temp=$temp->leftChild;
         }
   if($successor!=$delNode->rightChild)
     {
      $succParent->leftChild=$successor->rightChild;
      $successor->rightChild=$delNode->rightChild;
     }
  return($successor);
  }
//function to find the order of two strings
 public function find_order($str1,$str2)
  {
     $str1=strtolower($str1);
     $str2=strtolower($str2);
     $i=0;
     $j=0;

```
 $p1=$str1[i];
 $p2=$str2[j];
```

while(true)
   {
       if(ord($p1)

```
       return($str1);
     }
  else
     {
       if(ord($p1)==ord($p2))
         {
          $p1=$str1[++$i];
          $p2=$str2[++$j];
          continue;
         }
      return($str2); 
     }
```

}//end while

} //end function find string order

public function is_empty()
  {
    if($this->root==null)
      return(true);
    else
      return(false);
  }
}//end class BinaryTree
?>